# Questions about understanding wordCount example of Apache beam

Tags: java, apache-beam, word-count

I just started to learn Apache beam. For the wordCount example here: [https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#wordcount-example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/WordCount.java)

A few things I don't understand and nor can I find answers by googling.

1. The command line arguments are --inputFile and --output. However, I can not find any reference about the available arguments list, and I can't link these arguments to anywhere in the source code: [Git source code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/WordCount.java). Can someone please explain how/why those command line arguments work?
2. In the source code, in the WordCountOptions interface, there are four methods:

   String getInputFile();

   void setInputFile(String value);

   String getOutput();

   void setOutput(String value);

   They are not implemented by any class, nor do they have default implementations. As a result, I wonder why they can get/set the input and output?

Those questions may be very simple and obvious, but as a newbie, it's very confusing and there is a lack of explanation online. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a class and an interface in java, otherwise you need to learn that. And the options are documented in the file you linked to.

Comment: No, I know that WordCountOptions is an interface. What I don't understand is that, I don't see a class that implements these four methods, nor do I see any default implementation in the interface. So I don't understand how they can impact the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the problem. It's more than what I thought, and it involves some other concepts that are not obvious to newbie. I wrote my understanding here, hopefully it can help other starters who are confused as well.

1. The command line arguments is actually set with command `--inputFile=pom.xml` and `--output=counts`. It follows the default parsing specified here: [fromArgs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptionsFactory.html#fromArgs-java.lang.String...-)
2. A property named `inputFile` is defined by the getter and setter methods below:

   `String getInputFile();`

   `void setInputFile(String value);`

   Similarly, a property named `output` is defined by the getter and setter methods below:

   `String getOutput();`

   `void setOutput(String value);`

   Refer to **Defining Your Own PipelineOptions** section in here: [Interface PipelineOptions](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.7.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptions.html)

As a result, the argument values of `inputFile` (i.e., pom.xml) and `output` (i.e., counts) can be passed to the property and added to the options. The code `options.getInputFile()` gets the value of `inputFile` specified in command line, and `options.getOutput()` gets the value of `output`.

Comment: thanks for this. I also had the exact same question, I roughly knew what was going on but not sure how it could happen without any implementation of those methods. From reading your links it seems like it works because of Beans in Java, I'm not too familiar with that. I guess the docs just tell you how to use it but doesn't explain why it works..